# Should I split the site by language for better SEO when the English site has low quality content?

Tags: seo, url, internationalization, language

We have two versions of our website English and Arabic. Arabic is in a sub-directory (not a sub-domain).

When we started looking at SEO, we found that most of our articles are plagiarized from other sources. We are almost done with the optimization of our Arabic articles, however the English site contains too many articles and are not optimized for SEO.

For getting good results and to speed up the process, which of the following idea is better?

- We should separate the English and Arabic sites.
- We shouldn't separate the sites and remove most of the articles from English site.

Please let us know if there is another good option.

Comment: Are the English articles plagiarised or simply not optimised? And when you say plagiarised do you mean some has plagiarised your articles, or your articles are not original?

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks for reply. We have un-original content also they are not optimized. If we start, it will take long to optimize all articles.

Comment: When you say plagiarized, do you mean duplicate content? If so, setting up canonical links can help if you know where the original content is. If not, I would delete the duplicate content.

Comment: So you are suggesting to remove the duplicate articles. Our articles has several internal links which will give 404 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something to ensure that Google does not find low quality plagiarized content mixed in with higher quality content.   You are right to be worried.   Large amounts of low quality or copied content can get your entire site penalized such that it doesn't rank well.

Splitting the sites is one option that might work.

Another option would be to prevent Googlebot from crawling or indexing the low quality content.   Either user *robots.txt* to disallow crawling or include meta robots noindex tags to prevent it from showing up in the search results.

Comment: We have 1100 articles in English section. Most of them are plagiarized and not optimized for SEO. Also we want to speed up the SEO process. What do you suggest is it OK with too many urls in robots.txt. Or we should remove most of the articles and optimize the rest.

Comment: There is no such thing as overusing *robots.txt*.  I've worked with sites that have 10 disallowed URLs for every crawlable URL.